# Cohomology of the classifying space of a semidirect product, and some specific examples with cyclic groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ and $A$ be finite abelian groups and $\rho :G \rightarrow \text{Aut}(G)$ a representation of $G$. We can form the semidirect product $A\rtimes _{\rho} G$. Just to agree on the notation this is the set of pairs $(a,g)$ with product
$$
(a_1,g_1)\cdot (a_2,g_2)=(a_1\rho_{g_1}(a_2),g_1g_2)
$$

1. How can we compute the cohomology $H^*(B (A\rtimes _{\rho} G),\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ in terms of the cohomology of $BA$ and $BG$?
2. To be concrete I would need the following example: $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $A=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, with $N$ such that $\exists t \in \mathbb{Z} $, $t^2=-1\, \text{mod}(N)$, and $\rho_1(a_1,a_2)=(ta_2,-ta_1)$ (moreover, it it helps concreteness I would just need $H^3$).

Comment: Look up the serre spectral sequence. There is a fiber sequence $BA\to B(A\rtimes G) \to BG$.

Comment: Could you maybe describe more explicitly what you get in this way, at least in the specific example I mentioned?

Comment: If $N$ is odd, I think you get $H^3=\mathbb{Z}/2N$. If $N$ is even, it seems a bit more messy.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the question on the example. I am going to edit with the correct question

Comment: Like Achim said, you should get acquainted with the Leray-Serre spectral sequence. This isn't the right forum to ask for solutions to explicit computations. A nice feature of this spectral sequence is that for a semidirect product, no differentials start from the axes (because of the splitting). But there can be other differentials, as well as all kinds of extensions.

Comment: The description of the action $\rho $ in the second part of the question can be simplified.  It simply permutes the two generators (1.0) and (0, -t).  So this is just a quadratic construction (or extended p-th power with p=2) and there is full of litterature on the subject.

Comment: @user43326 could you be more explicit, or maybe provide some reference?

Comment: Basically the cohomology of the fiber splits as a Z[Z/2] module of the direct sum of free part F and trivial part T.  So in the Leray-Serre spectral sequence, from the free part you only get the invariants, from the trivial part  you get $H^*(Z/2,T)$ in $E^{\infty}$.

Comment: As these are all discrete groups, and the fundamental group of the base acts nontrvially on the fibre, you might be better off reading about the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence of a group extension, for which a good reference is Brown's book "Cohomology of groups".